# How can I make a prepared statement with IN() and have a while loop for PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PDO, and have got stuck on trying to create a prepared statement for using IN()

I have an array of different URLs ($urls), which I use for the IN(). I am not getting any errors, but the results are not showing.

```
    $in = str_repeat('?,', count($urls) - 1) . '?';
    $qry = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT categories_url,categories_id,parent_id,categories_name FROM categories WHERE categories_url IN($in)");
    $qry->execute($urls);
    while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['categories_url'];
    }
```

When I test the query with $qry->fetchColumn(), then it seems to have 0 results. But if I do the same query in mysqli, it has multiple results.

The things I am unsure about it, I dont think my prepared statement is quite right, or maybe its the execution. And I dont know how to do while loops with fetch_assoc with PDO prepared either. What have I done wrong?

Comment: It looks okay. Do other queries execute successfully with this connection? Have you configured the connection to throw exceptions?

Comment: This is a tangential comment, but I find it easier and more clear to do `$in = implode(',', array_fill(1, count($urls), '?'));` to create the placeholders.

Comment: It doesn't echo out the categories_url like it should, it says there are 0 results. I dont know what is wrong.

Comment: Have you enabled exceptions to be used for error reporting? You might just be having a syntax error.